# pyarrow: .parquet file that used to work perfectly is now unreadable

Tags: python, pandas, parquet, pyarrow

pyarrow: .parquet file that used to work perfectly is now unreadable.

The file was created with pandas a few days ago.

when trying to read the file:

```
pd.read_parquet(filename)
```

I get:

```
ArrowIOError: Corrupted file, smaller than file footer
```

What can cause this corruption? 
Is there a way to read the file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas cannot read parquet files created in PySpark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54201799/pandas-cannot-read-parquet-files-created-in-pyspark)

Comment: Can you please open a JIRA issue on https://issues.apache.org/jira/