# How to read directory that contains different parquets in parts?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, partitioning

Given a parquet dataset with a job_id `abc`, saved in parts as such:

```
my_dataset/
  part0.abc.parquet
  part1.abc.parquet
  part2.abc.parquet
```

It is possible to read the dataset with vaex or pandas:

```
import vaex
df = vaex.open('my_dataset')

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_parquet('my_dataset')
```

But sometimes our ETL pipeline appends to the the `my_dataset` directory with parts of parquet from another job id `xyz`, that caused the directory to becomes something like:

```
my_dataset/
  part0.abc.parquet
  part0.xyz.parquet
  part1.abc.parquet
  part1.xyz.parquet
  part2.abc.parquet
  part2.xyz.parquet
```

The main problem is we don't know the job ID created by the ETL pipeline, but we know that they are unique.

Is there some method in `pandas.read_parquet` to automatically group the parts together? E.g.

```
import pandas as pd
dfs = pd.read_parquet('my_dataset')
```

[out]:

```
{
 'abc': pd.DataFrame, # That reads from `part*.abc.parquet`
 'xyz': pd.DataFrame  # That reads from `part*.xyz.parquet`
}
```

I've tried doing some glob reading

Comment: I don't think it's currently supported from the box. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60140780/4727702) for the usage of `glob`

Comment: Wouldn't it be worth fixing the directory structure (e.g. with subdirectories?)

Comment: Not that I know of. If I were in your position and couldn't change the dir structure, I'd go with `glob` -> `sort` -> `groupby`.